# C#/MonoGame - Destroying large objects in memory when I unload my game level

Tags: c#, object, memory-management, garbage-collection, monogame

I'm working on a game using C#/MonoGame and I'm wondering how to solve a garbage collection problem relating to large game objects in memory.

Every time I load a new game, I create and store a `World` object which itself has a private field containing a quadtree for my LOD terrain system. The quadtree recursively contains vertex information for all its possible child nodes, down to the smallest level I've decided I want. This means that each new `World` takes ~10 seconds to create (done on a background thread) and comes to ~150MB in RAM size.

I'd like to be assured that every time I load a new game, the old `World` is disposed, but as far as I can tell right now, this is never happening. I just tested it by pressing 'load game' six times in a row, and the memory used by my game was touching 1GB without ever dropping.

I know this could mean that I'm still referencing my old `World` objects, but I can't see how this is happening. My main game app has a single private `World` which is re-created from scratch as a new object on my background loader thread every time I press 'load game':

```
// This belongs to the game and is referenced when I want to interact with and draw the current World
private World _world;
.
.
// Executes on background loader thread when I press 'load game'
LoadGame()
{
    // This is where the old World is replaced with the new one, so I want the old one to be disposed as it contains ~150MB of useless data
    _world = new World(worldParameters);
}
.
.
Draw()
{
    // Rendering the active World in our draw loop
    DrawWorld(_world);
}
```

I tried setting `_world` to null and forcing the GC to collect at the top of the `LoadGame()` method, but that did nothing.

Is there a way I can force the memory for the old object to be freed, or even just see if I'm inadvertently pointing to any of its fields in the rest of my game, causing it to stay alive?

Comment: Have you tried inheriting MonoBehavior and calling UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(_world) ?

Comment: @Iv Misticos That seems to be for Unity - I'm using MonoGame for C# which is a different framework (based on XNA).

Comment: Aw, sorry lol <3 good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation can be a tricky thing in garbage collected languages like C#. Ironically, these languages are designed so that you don't have to think too much about memory allocations. Unfortunately, for games having the garbage collector kick in during gameplay can be a frustrating experience for the player if keeping a consistent frame rate is important for your game.

There are two approaches that I'm aware of to deal with this kind of issue. The first is to explicitly call the garbage collector yourself.

```cs
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Keep in mind, this is a quick and dirty approach and it might not work the way you expect. Many people on the internet will tell you it's not recommended or a bad idea to force garbage collection. I'm no expert in the pros and cons, but I just wanted to make you aware that it's an option so you can do your own research.

The second approach is being smart about your data structures. Some circles might call this "implementing your own memory allocation strategy". Essentially what it boils down to is pre-allocating a big chunk of memory up front and reusing that space over and over again.

What the exact strategy looks like for you could be very simple, or very complex. My advice is to start with the simplest thing you can get away with and see how it goes. One of the patterns that might be helpful to look into is often called "object pooling".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I just discovered with a memory profiler that it's actually less of a garbage collection issue, and more of a problem with how I was handling unmanaged memory in MonoGame. My `World` object contains a terrain quadtree, where each node has a `VertexBuffer` containing its actual vertex data. I neeeded to recursively call `Dispose()` on every `VertexBuffer` before dereferencing my `World` object or all the vertex memory would be leaked. Every time I loaded a new game, I was leaving ~21,000 `VertexBuffers` in memory!